# Exception in ReverseGeocodeQuery

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, reverse-geocoding

I'm using `ReverseGeocodeQuery` to retrieve the addresses of many locations. The problem is that I'm getting an exceptiona as result, with following message:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041B57

Having a look to [ReverseGeocodeQuery Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.reversegeocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) reference in MSDN, I can see that it is listed in the possible error results with the Symbolic Code of `EErrorIndexFailure`. However, it doesn't give me more information about the error, and the StackTrace is null too.

My code is as folloing:

```
foreach (var ev in events)
{
    ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
    query.GeoCoordinate = ev.Location;
    query.QueryCompleted += (s, e)=>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        ev.city = e.Result[0].Information.Address.City;
    };
    query.QueryAsync();
}
```

Why am I getting this error, and how could I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the api is a little limited and it is not possible to make multiple `ReverseGeocodeQuery` calls simultaneously.

In order to make them one-by-one following the *async/await* pattern, I have implemented an extension method:

```
public static Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(this Query<T> query)
{
    var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    EventHandler<QueryCompletedEventArgs<T>> handler = null;

    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        query.QueryCompleted -= handler;

        if (e.Cancelled)
            taskSource.SetCanceled();
        else if (e.Error != null)
            taskSource.SetException(e.Error);
        else
            taskSource.SetResult(e.Result);
    };

    query.QueryCompleted += handler;

    query.QueryAsync();

    return taskSource.Task;
}
```

And, then I modified my code to execute the query the following way:

```
foreach (var ev in events)
{
    ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
    query.GeoCoordinate = ev.Location;
    var result = await query.ExecuteAsync();
    ev.city = result[0].Information.Address.City;
}
```

This way, a call is not made until the previous has finished. The downside of this approach is that it can take too long if we have many places.

Comment: Thank you!! That was one of the most amazing answer ever!